# weighted Average Loss Function Optimization

Tags: calculus

Can anyone help me in giving a vectorized expression obtained by optimizing this function w.r.t w? I tried the calculation, but it is still in form of summation and I am not able to simplify it. [A first Course in Machine Learning By Simon Rogers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFWEQ.png)

Comment: [Weighted least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares#Motivation)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.